# Socket.io with Next.Js with custom server, giving errors after deployment on Netlify

Tags: next.js, deployment, socket.io, netlify

**Hi Everyone!**

I have a problem that my next.js chatting web app is working fine on **localhost** but not on Netlify after deployment. First of all I want to ask does Netlify supports custom server or not, just like Vercel don't support it. If it does support custom server than what should I do?

I created a custom server for my next.js chatting app to connect with socket.io correctly. Until I were working on localhost it was fine. But that was not the case after deployment. It just show me now these errors :

```
GET https://chatu.netlify.app/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OnZ3dxq 404
```

here is the link of the website in case you want to check it personally
[My Website Link](https://chatu.netlify.app/)
**Use this userName and password for login:
UserName: user1
password : 1**